# Stack Overflow Button styling on iOS Safari

Tags: bug, design, mobile-safari

I've noticed that none of the buttons of Stack Overflow on iOS (Safari) are  styled properly - they inherit the OS style. The buttons currently look like native OS buttons, and I want them to follow StackExchange's style, because currently the white text is placed inside a very light blue which is not proper at all.

[image]

To fix this issue, the following could be added to buttons:

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
```

Comment: You mean you want buttons to look like native OS buttons?

Comment: No, The buttons are currently look like native OS buttons, and I want them to follow StackExchange's style, because currenty the white text is placed inside a very light blue which is not proper at all.

Comment: @Oded And it IS a design bug!

Comment: Well, you really need to clarify the report then.

Comment: I do understand the bug, +1 and voted to Leave Open however looks like others are failing to understand what you report. If you can add screenshots it can greatly help. (and no need to tell the developers what to do, I'm quite sure they can figure that on their own)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Thank you, I tried to capture some screenshot but my iOS device was not with me, I'll add it in a few mins.

Comment: Cheers, better now. :)