# Is there any consequence to incorrectly flagging or voting to close a question as a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, flags, vote-to-close

It happened quite a few times to me that a question of mine was incorrectly flagged as a duplicate of another question (usually a similar question that is not as specific as mine). Most of the times it is pretty obvious that my question differs just by comparing the titles (imo), but still, once the first close-vote is casted, it's usually like a snowball effect and other people seem to blindly vote for close too. This can be incredibly frustrating because I have to compensate for other peoples mistakes and the process can takes days. And don't get me started on getting a question reopened. It can be a pain...

Anyway, my actual question is, what happens to a user who incorrectly flagged something as a duplicate or even started a close vote? Does he/she at least get a notification or something like that?

Comment: Related on Meta Stack Overflow [What can I do if I believe that my question was wrongly marked as a duplicate?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253521/2415822).  Looking for a Meta Stack Exchange dupe now.

Comment: How do you quantify "incorrectly flagged something as a duplicate?"  Do you mean do users who vote to close a question get a notification if it has been reopened?  If so, no, there's nothing like that.

Comment: Not only users who vote close, also users who marked it as a duplicate.

Comment: It's basically the same thing.  There's nothing in place to notify users.

Comment: And what about something that prevents you from casting votes in the future or maybe something that makes your vote count less. I feel like there should be at least something. I mean if they don't have a chance to learn from their mistakes, then they will probably do the same thing over and over again.

Comment: That's at a moderator's discretion.

Comment: First, you go read the answers to the other duplicate.  They may actually answer your question, even if they aren't ***exactly*** the same.  If you can clearly state why the answers on the duplicate will not work for your question, then edit it and explain why.  You can @ the closer through a comment and ask them to review your update.

Comment: Most of the time I have found and already read the alleged "duplicate" including their answers long before I even asked the question. And yes obviously I go and edit my question to explain why it is not a duplicate, but this wastes so much time and makes me mad.

Comment: @Forivin You can prevent that by writing a sufficiently clear question in the first place, demonstrating your research effort, and not assuming that every reader is capable of reading your mind and knowing what you've done, why it does and doesn't work, etc.

Comment: In my opinion my questions are usually pretty clear. I mean I could of course attach my browsing history to it, but I feel like that shouldn't be necessary. For example take [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41706733/javascript-find-out-when-a-link-is-clicked-or-opened-in-another-way) (Okay it's not best question), but it was marked as a duplicate of something that isn't a duplicate at all. I'm not sure how I could have prevented that.

Comment: @Forivin That question has never been closed as a duplicate, nor does it have any close votes on it.  It's actually a great example that *contradicts* what you're suggesting happens.

Comment: It was just marked as a duplicate, it was not closed.

Comment: Exactly.  So nothing happened.  There was no problem.  Your question wasn't closed.  Someone thought a question was a duplicate, nobody agreed, and nothing happened.  There is no problem; there's nothing to solve.  The system worked.

Comment: Note that [only you see the "may already have an answer" banner at the top of the question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/167980/159251).

Comment: Even if a question is closed for being a duplicate which takes 5 votes normally, if that happens, it means the original suggestion can't possibly be wrong.  You don't seem to be very willing to accept the communities decision

Answer (score 9):

> Does he/she at least get a notification or something like that?

No. They don't. And there is often no need to. Everyone makes mistakes. From my point of view, the fault is often not entirely that of the user voting to close. Remember: a user voting to close wins nothing: no reputation points, no badges, nothing. So there is little reason for a user to vote to close besides the close reason given. Sometimes the question is formulated that way it is not to obvious to *them* it isn't a duplicate. And yes, as said, they make mistakes too. It happens.

Even related questions can have the same answer, so make sure to check if the answers are actually useful or not.

I usually stick around to see how a question goes after I flagged or voted on it, so I usually get the feedback that way, which is fine for me. No need for notifications.

> what happens to a user who incorrectly flagged something as a duplicate or even started a close vote?

Users flagging and voting just to abuse the system will get caught and punished. Wrongfully flagging is punished faster than voting to close, but that is just because flags are handled differently. A user who keeps behaving in a destructive manner can be flagged and will be acted on. If the user is really abusive, they can be suspended (they can't be taken away their privileges, so suspending is the only option for moderators).

Answer (score 4):

Define "wrongly."

Say I vote to close your question as a duplicate. If 4 other people also vote that way, it is closed. You may then edit your question to clarify that it is not a duplicate. People will now vote to re-open the question. That doesn't make me wrong. It means that what you had in your head didn't successfully make it to the screen, causing some people to believe it was a duplicate. This belief, and the action of closing, had the good effect of getting you to edit and improve your question. The site gets better. Nobody should be punished.

Now, say another time I vote to close a question as a duplicate. Nobody else who sees it votes the same way, and my close vote ages away. The question is never closed. No harm, no foul. In theory the system could take away some of my close votes, but how would that help anyone? There isn't really a problem to be solved.

The scenario I think you're trying to prevent is that I vote to close, 4 other people who can't be bothered to read or think just blindly vote along with me, and then without any editing or changes to the question, a white knight rides in and gets the question reopened because it never deserved to be closed. In this rather rare situation, you want the original close-voters punished, because they will then change their ways and this will save time and effort for the white knight, or anguish for the poor innocent who wrote a crystal-clear question that was only closed because people were lazy and couldn't be bothered to read or think. I don't share your confidence that such people even exist, never mind that they will improve if they're punished, but **how will the system detect** that this is happening? The mere re-opening of the question proves nothing. Questions are re-opened all the time, generally as a result of improvements that were **caused by the closing**. Perhaps re-opening without an edit might be taken as some sort of proof, but let me ask you this: *How can you tell whether the 5 close votes were mindless pileons and are wrong, or the 5 re-open votes were mindless pileons and are wrong?* Surely if mindless pileons are a common thing, they can happen in both directions.

In short, working out who was right, who was wrong, who was right then and is also right to have the opposite opinion now (because the question changed) is impossible for software. It might be possible for humans, but I don't think it's a good use of their time.

Action for you: if your question is "wrongly" closed as a duplicate, edit it so that people stop believing it's a duplicate. (See [Someone flagged my question as already answered, but it's not](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194476/someone-flagged-my-question-as-already-answered-but-its-not/194479#194479) ) If people read what you wrote and come to believe something false ("this is a duplicate of whatever") after they read it, then you need to write it differently. Not call them lazy or accuse them of not thinking and not reading. A hard lesson but a true one nonetheless. (see [Why don't people read the question before editing and commenting?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266071/why-dont-people-read-the-question-before-editing-and-commenting/266072#266072) )